# iteration over 3 large lists to compare and assign value python

Tags: python

I have a piece of code where I need to go through many lists to read and assign values

The code does the following:
First, for each element in the **entities** (1st list 1300), the code will read its text file that contains many **lines** (2nd list 5000) each line contains two values. After that, the code will check if the first value in each line exists in the **features** list (3rdlist 17000), if yes it will write the second value in the line into the matrix. 
The code is working but it is inefficient and extremely slow.(more than 12 hours)

```
 #first list
for i in range(len(entities_list)-1):
    fin = open('/home/rana/'+entities_list[i]+'.txt','r')
            #Second List
            for line in fin.readlines():
                 #Third List
                for j in range(len(features_list)-1):
                if features_list[j]==line.split()[0]:
                    co_occurrence_matrix[i,j]=float(line.split()[1])
```

I will appreciate if someone gives me an Idea how to solve this issue

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: ( `range(len(entities_list)-1)` doesn't use the last item, is this really wanted ? )

Comment: I use 3.5 and yes I don't want the last element

Comment: Can `feature_list` contain one entry multiple times?

Comment: what do you mean by one entry multiple times?

Comment: @Abrar - can you have multiple features of the same value in the `features_list` (e.g. `features_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]`  (notice the zero))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feature lookup in the inner loop is slow `O(n)` and repeated `1300x5000 ~ 6.5M` times. The first thing you can do is to convert the `features_list` to a `dict` and speed that lookup up to `O(1)` (eliminate the third loop):

```
features = dict(zip(features_list, range(len(features_list)-1)))
for i in range(len(entities_list)-1):
    with open('/home/rana/'+entities_list[i]+'.txt', 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
             key, value = line.split()
             if key in features:
                 j = features[key]
                 co_occurrence_matrix[i,j] = float(value)
```

Comment: same question about j

Comment: You're right, I've fixed that. We can use `dict` (hashmap).

Comment: I got error: string indices must be integers in the j = feature[feature]

Comment: I had a typo (`feature` instead of `features`), try now.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely optimize away the third loop by creating a map upfront:

```
# first create a matrix map for fast features lookup
features_map = {feature: index for index, feature in enumerate(features_list)}
for index, entity in enumerate(entities_list):
    with open('/home/rana/{}.txt'.format(entity), 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            feature, value = line.split()  # you might want to validate this, tho
            if feature in features_map:
                co_occurrence_matrix[index, features_map[feature]] = float(value)
```

You might be able to speed it up further by delegating your I/O part (loading of the files) over multiple threads if the files are particularly big.